# Detecting gestures using python

Tags: python

I thought to use my macbook's trackpad gestures to interact with my python programs,for example trigger a particular function for two finger tap or three finger swipe etc.Are there any python modules for detecting mac's trackpad gestures?

Answer (score 2):

There are things that allow you to see what happens with it.

See [here](http://blog.sendapatch.se/2009/november/macbook-multitouch-in-python.html).

But I would be really surprised Apple let people mess around with it.
Not really the policy of the family

I may be wrong, there seem to be [some hacks around](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/apple-magic-trackpad-hacks-and-158167) .
You will surely need a developer's license to have any information about that though.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about apple's 'keep it in a box and lock it' policy.