# Is there anyway I could find where my finger is kept on the trackpad in python

Tags: python, libraries, trackpad

Something like it returns the x,y position of the places where my finger is kept

Comment: see if this response helps you get the required answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344722/detecting-gestures-using-python

Comment: also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python